# Getting exception while trying to get SHA-1 key in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, sha

I want to get SHA-1 & SHA-256 keys. I am using Flutter. I ran the following command as mentioned in the documentation.

```
keytool -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

After execution, I got the following exception.

```
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available
java.io.IOException: Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available
        at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2167)
        at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:222)
        at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1479)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:1058)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:405)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:398)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available
        at java.base/javax.crypto.Mac.getInstance(Mac.java:191)
        at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2145)
        ... 5 more
```

Flutter Doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[!] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.12, on Deepin 20.9 5.15.77-amd64-desktop, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    ! Warning: `dart` on your path resolves to /usr/lib/dart/bin/dart, which is not inside your
      current Flutter SDK checkout at /home/vrs/flutter. Consider adding /home/vrs/flutter/bin to
      the front of your path.
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2023.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.77.3)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

What should I do?

Comment: can you add output of `flutter doctor` please ?

Comment: Added 'flutter doctor' output @ARK4579